# Getting SAML token from ADFS using windows credentials

Tags: c#, windows-8, sap, saml

I am creating a windows 8 client app in c#.This app will use odata service of SAP. For authentication I need SAML token issued by ADFS. Is there any method to get SAML token from ADFS using windows credentials?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the SAML token using the below code.

```
var factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.Bindings.UserNameWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential), adfsEndpoint);

factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "********";
factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;
WSTrustChannel channel = null;
try
{
    var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
    {
        RequestType = WSTrust13Constants.RequestTypes.Issue,
        AppliesTo = new EndpointAddress("https://yourserviceendpoint.com/"),
        KeyType = KeyTypes.Bearer,
    };
    channel = (WSTrustChannel)factory.CreateChannel();
    return channel.Issue(rst);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason to ignore the exception?